# Why does the Need review counter often appear inaccurate after a passed review audit?

Tags: support, review-audits, review-stats

After passing a review audit, and after the congratulations screen is shown, I sometimes click the `stats`-link to find out how many additional posts *need review*.

I noticed that the actual number shown, say `X`, is usually (always?) 1 less then the actual number of posts that still need review (= `X+1`). Because if I then just continue reviewing (using the `start reviewing now`-link), it turns out that there is usually (always?) 1 more review (total = `X+1`) that I can perform as compared to what was initially shown as *need review* (= `X`). This seems to happen on all sites where I perform reviews (and which have audit reviews enabled), for either first posts or late answers. Obviously, this to the extend that `X+1` does not exceed my daily maximum reviews of 20.

Of course, while completing the remaining reviews the number of posts to be reviewed could indeed change. But I find it suspicious that very often there is a difference of exactly 1 as described above.

What's the actual reason for this apparent difference, or is it simply a bug (like "*completing an audit review should not decrease the number of posts that need review*")?

For a real world illustration, which happened when I completed [this audit review:](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/1050623). The value that was shown for `X` was `2`, but nevertheless in the next 2 minutes or so I was able to complete `3` more reviews, i.e. [this one](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/1050590), and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/1050602), and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/1050578).

Note: in case `X=0` you better click the `start reviewing now`-link, because often times there is 1 (= `X+1`) review outstanding anyway ... as in [this audit review](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/1051205).

Comment: I couldn't recreate this, when I click the stats button it shows the same number as the all reviews page after a refresh. I think this might be just a coincidence. If it is on an active site, it seems likely someone else could be reviewing at the same time?

Comment: @MarkKirby pretty sure this is not a coincidence, it happened again a few hours ago on some other site, after I passed another audit review. And it only happens after such audit review (only then you have a chance to try to recreate it). Moreover IMO it has nothing to do with a *refresh*.